# Spring Boot resource spring.factories not available in the generated Artifact/jar

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

We have a library ,in order to auto-configure the library we use spring.factories file under(src/main/resources/META-INF) which provides classes to auto-configure my library.

Reference : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-custom-starter

I have below configuration in spring.factories file :

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=com.x.y.PubSubConfig
```

When I build my code spring.factories should be part of generated artifact but to my surprise I don't see any Meta-Inf in the jar.

On little resarch I believe it could related to the build plugin ,issue below describes some aspect around same. 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8299

My  problem is my spring.factories file is not shipped with my jar hence auto configuration does not happen . Below is my POM file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.kramphub</groupId>
    <artifactId>pubsub-template</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <google-cloud-bom.version>0.55.1-alpha</google-cloud-bom.version>
        <selfdiagnose.version>2.15.2</selfdiagnose.version>
        <lombok.version>1.16.22</lombok.version>

        <log4j-over-slf4j.version>1.7.25</log4j-over-slf4j.version>
        <assertj-core.version>3.10.0</assertj-core.version>
    </properties>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>kramphub-releases</name>
            <url>https://kramphub.jfrog.io/kramphub/libs-release-local</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>google-cloud-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${google-cloud-bom.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-pubsub -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.philemonworks</groupId>
            <artifactId>selfdiagnose</artifactId>
            <version>${selfdiagnose.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j-over-slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${assertj-core.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- verify whether necessary -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-source-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>testwithemulator</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-javadoc-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: You aren't using the Spring Boot plugin so I don't see how the issue is related. My guess your `META-INF/spring.factories` isn't in `src/main/resource` but in `src/main/java`.

Comment: 1. Spring.factories file is in src/main/resources and I have also tried using spring-boot-maven-plugin , no luck ! If you have any leads to debug the problem please share . Thanks

Comment: Also if i use spring-boot-maven-plugin  It forces me to give a main class, which I dont want to have considering we are making a library !

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` you are creating a regular jar not a Spring Boot jar. You are linking to an issue that is related to the Spring Boot plugin (which you aren't using) so the issue you are linking to is irrelevant. When using the default jar plugin without further configuration it will copy those things. So you must be reconfiguring something in  your build (maybe to parent does that).